# Excel sheet loses formatting and sheet structure

Tags: excel, windows-10, ms-office

I distribute Excel spreadsheets as Balanced Scorecard tools to all my clients. I have just received once back where a sheet, one of many in the workbook, has been changed:

1. All hidden rows and columns have been unhidden
2. Sheet protected has been set to not protected
3. Most of the formatting has been lost
4. Functional images on row one have been removed
5. Set column widths have been reset to default
6. Grids are turned on

The following two images show what the sheet should look line and what has happened.

**Before:**

[image: Before]

**After:**

[image: After]

The customer runs Office 2016 on a Windows 10 PC.

Has anyone seen this happen before?

Can anyone tell me what causes this to happen?

Comment: The second image seems to not be displayed. Click on either of the number 2's...

Comment: I just fixed that

Comment: Too quick for me... Thanks

Comment: Perhaps a silly question, but was the sheet protection password protected?

Comment: As per the image, this is a xlsm (Macro) file. Maybe the macros are disabled on customer's PC?

Comment: The sheet was protected but whatever happened left it unprotected.

Comment: The macros need to be enabled to open the workbook so it's safe to assume macros are enabled on the client side.

Comment: This has just happened on another user's system. Help!